# Make parent component call a function angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I have parent component `UserComponent` which has few child routes. I want to be able to call a function in `UserComponent` from any child route. That's because both `UserComponent` and for example it's child component `ProfileComponent` use function in `UserService` to get the data they need to display, but when I edit the data in `ProfileComponent`, data are not refreshed in `UserComponent` (as it fetches all data after the instance is created ( ngOnInit() ), I guess it's not listening for changes).

CODE `UserComponent`:

```
error: string;
user: IProfile | {};

constructor(private router: Router, private userService: UserService) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.getUser();
}

getUser() {
  this.userService.getProfile().subscribe(
    response => this.user = response,
    error => this.error = error
  );
}
```

CODE `ProfileComponent`:

```
user: IProfile | {};
error: string;

constructor(private userService: UserService) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.userService.getProfile().subscribe(
    response => {
      this.user = response;
    },
    error => this.error = error
  );
}

update() {

  ...

  this.userService.updateProfile(data).subscribe(
    response => console.log(response),
    error => this.error = error
  );  
}
```

CODE `UserService`:

```
  private profileURL = 'http://localhost:4042/api/v1/profile';

  constructor(private http: Http) {}

  getProfile(): Observable<Object> {
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('access_token') });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    return this.http.get(this.profileURL, options)
                    .map(this.handleResponse)
                    .catch(this.handleError);
}

private handleResponse(data: Response): IProfile | {} {
  return data.json() || {};
}

private handleError (error: Response | any): Observable<Object> {

  ...

  return Observable.throw(errMsg);
}

updateProfile(data): Observable<Object> {
  let body = JSON.stringify(data);
  let headers = new Headers({ 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('access_token'), 'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8' });
  let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

  return this.http.patch(this.profileURL, body, options)
             .map((response: Response) => response)
             .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Comment: I'd use an observable to notify the components when the profile data has changed and cause them to requery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to John Baird I was able to create an `updated = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false)` in the `UserService` which contained the information if the profile was edited or not. When I edited the profile from child component I set that subject's next value to true `this.updated.next(true)`. On the other side I subscribed that subject for changes in the `UserComponent` and on subject's value change I fired the `getProfile()` function which updated the data.